# Open and Read text files in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pycharm

I'm trying to create a notepad-type program in Tkinter and Can't work out how to display a file's contents to a Label...

I have been able to display it's contents to the pyCharm shell but when I try to show in a label I get an error.

```
def openFile():
    fToOpen = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text files","*.txt")])
    #print(fToOpen.read()) <-- ##This works##
    fileToOpen = open(fToOpen, 'r')
    Label(root, fileToOpen.read()).pack() <-- ##This doesn't##
    fToOpen.close()
```

The error I get is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:/Users/Hello/Documents/html/Python/Prog.py", line 143, in openFile
>     Label(root, fileToOpen.read()).pack(fill=Y)
>   File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
>     Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
>   File "C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2289, in __init__
>     classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
> ```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you considered reading tkinter's Label documentation?

Comment: I have and I have made a minor breakthrough: I forgot to put text=fToOpen.read() but now in the Label, it is displaying the console error...

Comment: I have solved it now. I asked to open the file instead of file name then displayed the file in text=fToOpen.read() - Thankyou!

Comment: Are you sure `print(fToOpen.read()) <-- ##This works##` really works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually rather simple.

All you need to do is open the file and read the information into the `text` attribute of the widget.

This can be done as below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    Label(root, text=f.read()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```